# How to use jackson in Java if a json can represent 2 classes?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Jackson to deserialize objects in Java, e.g. here's one of hello world examples:

```
Foo foo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFoo, Foo.class);
```

There's a problem with my json string, though: it may be either

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"404",
      "message":"Not Found"
   }
}
```

or

```
[{fooFields}, {fooFields}]
```

So usually for the latter case, I would use:

```
Foo[] foos = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFoo, []Foo.class);
```

or

```
Error error = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFoo, Error.class);
```

How can I try to parse `jsonFoo` to either `Error` or `[Foo]` and return another custom `Error` object if there's an exception?

Currently, I only managed to come up with a nested try-catch construction which doesn't look really nice.

```
try {
     Foo[] foos = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFoo, []Foo.class);
     return new Bar(foos);
     catch {
          try {
          Error error = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFoo, Error.class); 
          return new Bar(error); 
          catch (IOException e)... // new Bar(InvalidInputError);
     }
     return new Bar(InvalidInputError);
```

Is there a way to rewrite it in a more concise way?

Comment: Is there some other way to tell that the json will be the error... like an error code returned from the request that got you the json, if it was one?

Comment: `if (jsonFoo.startsWith("{")) { /* parse to Error class here */ } else if (jsonFoo.startsWith("[")) { /* parse to Foo[] here */ } else { /* invalid JSON found */ }`

Comment: @BasilBourque changed the title

Answer (score 0):

I usually use JsonNode.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonStr1 = "[{\"key\":\"value\"}]";
    JsonNode jsonNode1 = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStr1);
    boolean array = jsonNode1.isArray();

    String jsonStr2 = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
    JsonNode jsonNode2 = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStr2);
    boolean object = jsonNode2.isObject();
}
```

[More information](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html)